# Android Wearable Emulator setup fail - visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Trying to install the Android wearable emulator using Android Device Manager and its failing. From logs can see that it downloads the zip package but failed to unzip it. Here is the device manager call stack. Thanks for your help!

> [19-04-09 14:16:05.74] Downloaded file '\AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk\x86-P_r02.zip' not found for Android SDK archive 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/x86-P_r02.zip' [19-04-09 14:16:32.15] [ProgressMonitor] downloading did end AVD Name: my_device [19-04-09 14:16:33.44] Installing Android SDK component: Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image r2 [System Image: X86 API 28 "P"] (system-images;android-P;android-wear;x86) [19-04-09 14:16:33.48] Unzipping file '\AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk\x86-P_r02.zip' to directory '\AppData\Local\Temp\16eb2381' [19-04-09 14:16:33.49] Exception caught while unzipping '\AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk\x86-P_r02.zip' in '\AppData\Local\Temp\16eb2381'. ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: The entry record signature field does not match the expected value for the Central Directory Entry Record signature. at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.ReadEntries() at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile..ctor(String name) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Manager.Helper.Unzip(String baseDirectory, String archivePath, String fileOwnerName) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Common.BasePackage.InstallArchive(String description, String archivePath, String targetDirectory) [19-04-09 14:16:33.49] Attempt to unzip Android component 'Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image r2 [System Image: X86 API 28 "P"]' found in \AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk\x86-P_r02.zip failed. [19-04-09 14:16:33.49] System.InvalidOperationException: Archive installation failed. at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Common.BasePackage.DoInstall(String archivePath, String androidSDKRoot) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Common.BasePackage.Install(String archivePath, String androidSDKRoot) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Repository.InstallComponent(IAndroidComponent component, String archivePath, String androidSDKRoot) [19-04-09 14:16:33.49] System.InvalidOperationException: Archive installation failed. at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Common.BasePackage.DoInstall(String archivePath, String androidSDKRoot) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Common.BasePackage.Install(String archivePath, String androidSDKRoot) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Repository.InstallComponent(IAndroidComponent component, String archivePath, String androidSDKRoot) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Repository.Install(IAndroidComponent component, String archivePath, String androidSDKRoot) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.InstallComponent(IAndroidComponent c, AndroidSdkInstance instance) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller.Install(AndroidSdkInstance instance, IList`1 componentsToInstall, Boolean throwIfInvalidComponentsFound) at Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.Manager.AndroidSDKComponent.<>c__DisplayClass56_0.b__0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: Use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) instead.

Comment: is there a visual studio integration available for genymotion?

Comment: No need to VS integration, as soon as you run the emulator's device you will see the device in VS. (_actually adb take care of everything for you_)